# Stock quantity not increasing after cancellation

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, stock

I have installed Magento 1.8. When a user orders a product, the quantity is decreased by one, but if he cancels that order (before invoicing), the stock quantity does not gets increased.

**Admin** > **Catalog** > **Inventory** > **Stock Options** > **Set Items Status to be In Stock When Order is Cancelled** is set to ***Yes***

The code I have been using to cancel order is as follows:

```
class Kaushikamdotcom_Pay_OrderController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function cancelAction() {
        if (($order_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id'))) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);

            $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true);
            $order->save();
        }

        $this->_redirect('sales/order/history');
    }
}
```

The code I have been using to know the current stock is as follows (The same can be also seen in the admin side):

```
Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
```

Why is the quantity not get increased ? Is it the intended behavior ? I searched in google, on [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330140/magento-increase-qty-upon-cancel-a-shipped-order/13330543#13330543) links I have been instructed to do it programmatically.

Comment: Please check Backorders is enabled in product -inventory tab....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was only changing the state of the order. That was not the correct way to do cancellation. I have found out an elegant way to do that [here](http://en.herveguetin.com/allow-customers-to-cancel-their-orders.html#.UyP0EXWSzI8).

**The relevant code from this tutorial is:**

```
if(!$order->canCancel()) {
    throw new Exception('Order cannot be canceled anymore.');
}
$order->cancel();
$order->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code for cancelling an order.

```
$orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$orderModel->load($orderId);
if(!$orderModel->canCancel()) {
$orderModel->cancel();
$orderModel->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true)->save();
$orderModel->save();
}
```

In your code, actual code is missing for cancel the order, you had never called `cancel()` function of class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try and hook on the `order_cancel_after` event and refund the ordered quantity using the event.

Answer (score 0):

Your code just change order status. If you want to return item to stock you should use Mage_Sales_Model_Order::cancel() instead, or if payment method doesn't support cancelation try Mage_Sales_Model_Order::registerCancellation.

This method cancel all order items and return it to stock.

```
        foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
            ...
            $item->cancel();
        }
```